# undefined method 'body' for nil:Nilclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am writing integration test for my application. For the following test, I am getting

```
undefined method 'body' for nil:Nilclass
```

My RSpec code:

```
        it "should not make a new user" do
            visit signup_path
            fill_in "Name", :with => ""
            fill_in "Email", :with => ""
            fill_in "Password", :with => ""
            fill_in "Confirmation", :with => ""
            click_button "Sign up"
            response.should render_template('users/new')
            response.should have_selector("div#error_explanation")
        end
```

Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @title = "Sign Up"
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @title = @user.name
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
    # Handle a successful save.
        flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
        redirect_to @user
    else
        @title = "Sign Up"
        render 'new'
    end
  end
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

test.log:

```
  [1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"[0m [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  begin transaction
Started GET "/signup" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-06 19:22:35 +0530
Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (46.8ms)
  Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (93.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (15.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 203ms (Views: 140.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-06 19:22:36 +0530
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"name"=>"", "email"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[35mUser Exists (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('') LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (15.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 47ms (Views: 15.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  rollback transaction
```

Error:

```
5 errors prohibited this user from being saved:

There were problems with the following fields:

    Name can't be blank
    Email can't be blank
    Email is invalid
    Password can't be blank
    Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)
```

What is missing/wrong in this code?

Comment: hi - you'll need to provide us a bit more info to help you solve this? In your terminal window (or if not, then in `test.log`) you will see the error listed above, and after that will be the stacktrace (that's about 20ish lines of filenames). Can you copy the top five-or-so lines of that and edit your question and paste it in? That will help us pinpoint what line in which file is causing the problem. Secondly - if you run your rails server locally and try to sign up with the above details, what happens?

Comment: Finally - can you please copy and paste the relevant sections of controller and template code into your question (because that's where the bug is right?). Especially anywhere that might use the word 'body'. Thanks :)

Comment: @TarynEast: Please see the edit. I have put controller here.

Comment: I still need the stacktrace to determine whether the error was thrown by the controller or the view (and which view). Also - *"Especially anywhere that might use the word 'body'. "* - this part was important.... you have an error that refers to `body` being called on something... so you have to find the part of your code that tries to call `body` on something.

Comment: @TarynEast: Please find the log.

Comment: Cool, so there's no server error, there's no message about unpermitted params. That means the problem is probably in the template. i want you to start the rails server locally - then go to the signup page in your browser, type in nothing, hit submit and see what happens. You should get an error visible in the page. Show me that.

Comment: @TarynEast: When I print the response after visit, it was blank. When I used get, it gives Capybara::ElementNotFound for the fields which I am filling in.

Comment: Ok, you're talking about GET which confuses me. When are you calling GET? what line of code is the capybara spec failing on? (you will see this in the stacktrace for the failing spec)

Comment: Also: do a project-wide search for the word `body` in your project (concentrate on the app-directory). somewhere related to signing up, you are calling `body` on something that hasn't been set up (ie its value is nil)... this is the error you are getting... so if you can find all the places where you use `body` - one of them will be the bug.

Comment: @TarynEast: I hope I am doing something wrong with visit. Visit should give me a response. But I am getting response object which is nil and that complains about Nil class. Any clue about using visit correctly.

Comment: No, the real error is in somewhere that uses `body` visit is not being used wrong - there is nothing wrong with it. Often, and error that occurs is caused by some other part of the code: one line of code calls another method, calls another method and it's the method at the bottom of the stack that has the error... but the error gets passed up the chain until it reaches the top before you hear about it.

Comment: `visit` is the method at the top of the chain. It's calling some other method deep in your code and the error is happening somewhere else. You need to find the real source of the error. *please* just do as I ask and look for `body` :)  The exact error is that something is nil and `body` is being called *on* this nil. Once you find where `body` is being called... you will then know what is nil (when it probably shouldn't be) and be able to figure out what is setting that thing to nil instead of what you expect and then your problem will be solved. But the very first step is to find `body`

Comment: `body` must be called over the `response` as `response` has a method body. If `response` is valid, then there is valid `body` which mostly contains HTML code of the page. It is because I have iterated over the methods of `response`. So, it seems that `response` is `nil`.

Comment: So - in a feature spec - you'll usually look at `page` instead of `response`. instead of your `response.should`s, try `expect(page).to have_content("")` and then put some words into the have-content string that you actually see written on the new-form (eg the page title). Make sure to have the same capitalisation as it's finicky about that